# 2 window.onload in 2 separate .js files, only 1 function loads

Tags: javascript, conflicting-libraries

I have 2 external JavaScript files which both call functions via **window.onload**. The files conflict, so only the second js file is working.

How would I fix the **window.onload** so both functions work? Should I do this in the HTML file or can I fix it in one of the js files?

The HTML header is:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="house.css" />
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow_library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="house.js"></script>
```

house.js:

```
    var $ = function(id){
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var calculateClick = function() {
    console.log("click, calculate click is running");
    //blahblahblah, lots of code
}

window.onload = function(rental){
    console.log("onload, javascript is running");
    console.log(rental);

    $("calculate").onclick = calculateClick;
}
```

Second window.onload is in 2 js files:

slideshow.js:

```
var slideShow;

window.onload = function (slideShow) {
    var params = {
        //blahblahblah lots of code
    }
}
```

slideshow_library.js:

```
var $ = function(id) { 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}

var SlideShow = function( params ){
    //blahblah blah even more code
} 
SlideShow.prototype.displayImage = function(){
    //blahblah blah even more code
}
SlideShow.prototype.displayNextImage = function(){
    //blahblah blah even more code
}
SlideShow.prototype.displayPreviousImage = function(){
    //blahblah blah even more code
}
SlideShow.prototype.togglePlay = function(){
    //blahblah blah even more code 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't use the old `window.onload` event model. That is not very flexible — as you've noticed — and not necessary for browser support any more.

jQuery makes this easy; change `window.onload = function` to `$(function)` in each JS file.

Pure JS solution: change that to `window.addEventListener('load', function)`.

Comment: What if you were to combine the two javascript files, how do you do that? I have an onload on 1 file, but not in the other. (And I want to bundle all of my javascript files)

Comment: @ganders: If one file is wrapped in an onload and the other isn't, then you can just concatenate the two files.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed/familiar to use JQuery, it would have been done like:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    //<-- do the rest here..
});
```

If you are still looking for pure js, try this example, its not on `window.onload` instead it uses `document.readyState`:

> first.js

```
(function(window, document) {
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        if('complete' === document.readyState) {
            clearInterval(t);
            alert('first js loaded ...');
        }
    }, 10);
})(window, document);
```

> last.js

```
(function(window, document) {
    var t = setInterval(function() {
        if('complete' === document.readyState) {
            clearInterval(t);
            alert('last js loaded ...');
        }
    }, 10);
})(window, document);
```

[Find the git repo here](https://github.com/arvind-web-corner/multiple-js-work-on-document-ready)